# Options on bash script (completely new to this)

Tags: linux, bash

So I'm beginning making bash scripts. I can do basic stuff, but that's it.

I want to make something so when I type in:

```
./myprogram -t
```

It will do "echo true"

And if I type in:

```
./myprogram -f
```

It will do "echo false"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The positional parameters are available through the variables `$1` `$2` etc.

There are many ways to implement the contition. You could use an if statement:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" = -t ] 
then
  echo true
elif [ "$1" = -f ] 
then
  echo false 
fi
```

A case statement:

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in 
  -t) echo true ;;
  -f) echo false ;;
esac
```

Or a short-circuit:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ "$1" = -t ] && echo true
[ "$1" = -f ] && echo false
```

For more complex cases consider using the `getopt` or the `getopts` libraries.

Answer (score 2):

The word for what you are calling an "option" is typically referred to as an argument in programming. You should read more about how to handle arguments in bash by reading everything at http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/othertypesv.html .  To answer your direct question the script might look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo 'No Arguments'
    exit 0
fi


if [ $1 = "-f" ]; then
    echo false
elif [ $1 = "-t" ]; then
    echo true
fi
```